# What is the relation between ADS-B MOPS & quality indicators?

Tags: ads-b, transatlantic

I have some questions about ADS-B & MOPS,

1. What is MOPS,
2. What is the relationship between MOPS and ADS-B out and Ground Station
3. Does the ADS-B have MOPS
4. If we have Ground Station with different MOPS at least than the ADS-B transponder, what will happen?
5. What is the relationship between MOPS and Quality indicators

Comment: A little feedback from the close voters would be nice…

Comment: @MichaelHall Close votes are about the post being too broad. and given that currently contains 5 questions, I see the point.

Answer (score 1):

The **MOPS** stands for Minimum Operational Performance Standard. It is a document that describes exactly how the transponder should create and transmit ADS-B messages. The document is maintained by combined standardisation committees of RTCA (Standardisation Committee 186) and EUROCAE (Working Group 51). The document is named RTCA DO-260 (A,B,C,..) or EUROCAE ED102 (A,B,...)

The ADS-B MOPS (for 1090MHZ Extended Squitter)  went through various versions (DO260/ED102, DO-260A, DO260B/ED102A, DO-260C/ED102B .  The MOPS version used in the transponder is transmitted as a number in one of the ADS-B messages.

0. = DO260  / ED102
1. = DO260A
2. = DO260B / ED102A
3. = DO260C

---

### Quality indicators

NUCp NUCv

NIC NACp NACv SIL SDA GVA NICbaro

More to be added later